# Apply tags just for one headline?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, spacemacs

I have a global tags for tasks, but I would like a specific tags for projects that should not be applied to tasks. I tried using `#+TAGS:` under `Projects` headline, but those tags still apply to tasks.

---

EDIT.

My Current Setting:

```
#+TAGS SCHOOL(S) HOME(H) PHONE(p) COMPUTER(c)
* Tasks
* Projects
#+TAGS ACADEMIC(A) PERSONAL(P) ADMINISTRATIVE(a) RESEARCH(R)
** Project A       :PERSONAL:
*** Project Plans
**** Task 1 for Project A 
**** Task 2 for Project A 
*** Project Support Materials
```

I wanted to confine second TAGS definition to subheadlines of `Projects` headline so that it won't interfere with the first TAGS definitions.

Comment: Okay, that's a lot more interesting than what I initially thought you were asking about.  But I have no clue how to help.  Sorry!  I've deleted my answer, now that it's clear it's off-base.

Comment: No worries! Thank you for your help